# How do I move my release file to next step of Azure Builds process?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, wix

I have a successful running build in Azure Pipelines that uses Wix Toolset to create an installer .msi file. I'm using the msbuild task to produce installer file.

As you may already know the build agent places it buried in work folder as shown below:

```
C:\agent\_work\2\s\SetupProject1\bin\Release\SetupProject.msi
```

What is the next step to move this setup file to a target server (Dev, QA, or Prod servers)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the next step to move this setup file to a target server (Dev, QA, or Prod servers)?

You need to add a `Publish artifacts task` (e.g. [Publish build artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops)
 and [Publish Pipeline Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops)) after the `msbuild` step.

For example:

```
- task: MSBuild@1
.....

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'setup file Path' 
    ArtifactName: 'artifact name'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

The publish artifacts task could publish the build files as artifacts. Then you could use the artifacts in Release Pipeline.

[image: Build Artifacts]